# I added CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK=y into android-base.cfg file and I don't know how can I get effect of that line. Any Idea?

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, linux-kernel

I want to enable kmemleak tool on android kernel for kernel level memory leakage detection. For that I added CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK = y line into android-base.cfg file and then rebuild it 
but still I could not enable kmemleak on android. Please help me out.

Ref: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kmemleak.txt